# How to pass multiple values to the create action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, comments

In my app I have `User`, `Post` and `Comment` models.

When a `User` wants to comment on `Post` the new action from the `Comments` controller takes over. The `Post` (to be commented on) is shown and the `User` enters his `Comment`.

However, when the User submits, I want to pass the Post.id and the Comments.content to the create action. How do I do that?

Here is the `comments/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Done" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks to all of you. I did the nested routing and my new.html.erb now has

```
<%= form_for [@post,@comment] do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<% f.hidden_field :post %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Done" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

However I get: undefined method `comment' and I cant figure that bugger out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that each `Comment` must belong to a `Post`  If that's the case then this seems like the perfect candidate for nested routes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

So in your case both the post id and the comment id would be part of the URL:

```
# Will submit to a URL like /posts/1/comments
# or /posts/1/comments/1
<%= form_for [@post,@comment] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Done" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You would need to handle the post_id in your comments controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to pass `Post.id` to the comments new action. Something like

```
link_to "Add comment", new_comment_path( params[ :id ] )
```

I assume that you're following conventions so `params[ :id ]` is `Post.id`. Later in your `Comment#create` instantiate new comment with

```
@comment = Comment.new( :post_id => params[ :id ] )
```

which will create comment related to the post. Finally form for new comment

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Done" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view (using HAML)

```
=form_for( @comment, :as => :comment) do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :post_id
  =f.hidden_field :user_id
  =f.text_area :comment
  =f.submit "Submit"
```

and in the Comment#new controller:

```
@comment = Comment.new(:user_id => @user.id, :post_id => @post.id)
```